# R question: the digit number is totally diffrent between seq(-0.65,0.65,by=0.1) and seq(-0.6,0.6,by=0.1)?

Tags: r, digits

in the same R, and it shows like this, it is really confusing!

```
seq(-0.65,0.65,by=0.1)

[1] -0.65 -0.55 -0.45 -0.35 -0.25 -0.15 -0.05  0.05  0.15  0.25  0.35  0.45  0.55  0.65

seq(-0.6,0.6,by=0.1)

[1] -6.000000e-01 -5.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01  1.110223e-16  1.000000e-01
[9]  2.000000e-01  3.000000e-01  4.000000e-01  5.000000e-01  6.000000e-01
```

Comment: You can use `options(scipen = 999)` to avoid the scientific notation

Answer (score 1):

We can set the `options` to avoid the scientific notation

```
options(scipen = 999)
```

The issue is with the precision for the second case

```
seq(-0.6, 0.6,by = 0.1)
#[1] -0.5999999999999999777955 -0.5000000000000000000000 -0.3999999999999999666933 -0.2999999999999999333866 -0.1999999999999999555911
#[6] -0.0999999999999999777955  0.0000000000000001110223  0.1000000000000000888178  0.2000000000000000666134  0.3000000000000000444089
#[11]  0.4000000000000000222045  0.5000000000000001110223  0.5999999999999999777955
```

resulting in showing the output format in scientific notation

If we `round` the values, it will show

```
round(seq(-0.6,0.6,by=0.1), 2)
#[1] -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6
```